# Boxlayouts in Scrollview

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I would like to ask your help.

The scrollable structure under the [link](https://15530009509605697547.googlegroups.com/attach/2b8567ec8ce16/kv.PNG?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHVbK2KjdxSqxXbLZp6pNVtK1O2XkF_Qnn6HYWVDfLDs7Yj_xiNkKjlmrPzOi9_0pKdOCI-0eMzXwldap8iPHM--exI1P3crP3thNcuRGQmMTjxc-s) is what I want to generate.

As the Scrollview accept only one element, I used a GridLayout. Somehow I cannot put any Boxlayout in the GridLayout.

Could you help me? Did I made a mistake? Should I use maybe an other Layout? if yes, which one?

Thank you.

Here is the output of my .kv file:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg9o2.jpg

Here is the result, if I change  cols:1  to  cols:2   :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrLxT.jpg

Here is the code I tried in the .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.8.0
RootWidget:

    # import container
    container: container

    # fill container
    BoxLayout:
        id: container
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 0
        spacing: 3

        ScrollView:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}


            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                padding: 0
                spacing: 3
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height
                do_scroll_x: False

                BoxLayout:
                    height: 260
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 0.7, 0.7, 0.9
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos


                BoxLayout:
                    height: 260
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 0.7, 0.7, 0.9
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos


                BoxLayout:
                    height: 260
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 0.7, 0.7, 0.9
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos

                #type
                Label:
                    height: 260
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    text: 'Typ'

                BoxLayout:
                    height: 260
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 0.7, 0.7, 0.9
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set `height` or `width` or anything else with sizing you need to do something first in a widget you want to set it for:

```
size_hint: None, None
```

This will disable setting those properties according to parent's size and some other stuff i.e. number of widgets in parent (three widgets = parent's size / 3 for each) at least for layouts such as `BoxLayout` or `GridLayout`. Check [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#kivy.uix.layout.Layout) for more.

Alternatively use `size_hint_x: None` or `size_hint_y: None` and let the other part be set automatically if you only want to set one of `height` or `width`.